# .htaccess how to remove subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I have a website in which I want to enter

```
http://mysite.com/myfolder
```

but go to (load index.php from)

```
http://mysite.com/dir/myfolder
```

So which kind of `RewriteRule` should I use?

The following rule didn't work and it caused an "500: Internal Server Error" in all pages.

```
RewriteRule ^$ dir/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dir/$1
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The following should work as long as no path includes the "dir" string:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !dir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (?!^dir/)^(.*)$ /dir/$1 [L,NC]
```